NewtonSoft JSON deserialization of unknown fields
I'm parsing a thirdy part API, in my c# application, of that API I don't have any schema or specifications: to parse the responses I usually collect several answers and write classes that fit the JSON (this can be easily done by Visual Studio or online by JSON2CSHARP).
But there's an issue in this approach, when values for a key are null, I can't go further in desuming the value fitting classes. In theese cases I would like to use string? as property type and put in the property value the serialized nested JObject or JArray.
So when the application threw an exception in reading the following nested property:
<parents>.registrations[0].product_info
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '<parents>.registrations[0].product_info', line 1, position 5138

instead of "product_info": null,
[Edit]
as in my usual response:
{
    "head_test":"------HEAD-------",

    "product_info": null,
    
    "tail_test":"------TAIL-------"
}

I received a nested object
{
    "head_test":"------HEAD-------",

    "product_info": {
        "product_data": [
               {
                    "product_xtra": {
                    "product_xtra_id": "<an ID>",
                    "product_xtra_type": "<a string with the market type>",
                    "unit_price": "<a price label>",
                    "vat_rate": 0.22
                },
                "amount": 2,
                "price": "<another price label>"
            }
        ],
        "product_total_price": "<total price label>"
    },
    
    "tail_test":"------TAIL-------"
}

So I wrote a converter as following
public class JsonObjectToStringConverter<TValue> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(base.CanWrite)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => base.CanRead;

    public override bool CanWrite => base.CanWrite;

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = serializer.Deserialize<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>(reader);
        try
        {
            return token?.ToObject(objectType);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Failed to convert {token} to {objectType}", token, objectType);
            return token?.ToString();
        }

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if(value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var token = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(value);
            token.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Failed to convert {value} to json", value);
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        }

    }
}

My question is: can I avoid The try/catch block to check if the object can be normally deserialized? How can I do that?
Yesterday I tested this by adding an attribute in the target DTO class.
class Root{
    [JsonProperty("head_test")]
    public string? Head { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("product_info")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonObjectToStringConverter<object?>))]
    public string? ProductInfo { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("tail_test")]
    public string? Tail { get; set; }
}

It seemed to work but I would like to improve it. Thanks.
I Added a fiddle here, with a working snippet.
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

                    
public class Program
{
    static string json = """
    {
        "head_test":"------HEAD-------",
        "product_info": {
            "product_data": [
              {
                "product_xtra": {
                  "product_xtra_id": "<an ID>",
                  "product_xtra_type": "<a string with the market type>",
                  "unit_price": "<a price label>",
                  "vat_rate": 0.22
                },
                "amount": 2,
                "price": "<another price label>"
              }
            ],
            "product_total_price": "<total price label>"
          },
        "tail_test":"------TAIL-------",
    }
""";
    static string json2 = """
    {
        "head_test":"------HEAD-------",
        "product_info": "----INFO-----",
        "tail_test":"------TAIL-------",
    }
""";
    
        static string json3 = """
    {
        "head_test":"------HEAD-------",
        "product_info": null,
        "tail_test":"------TAIL-------",
    }
""";
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(root.ProductInfo ?? "<null>");
    
    
        Console.WriteLine(json2);
    
        var root2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json2);
        Console.WriteLine(root2.ProductInfo ?? "<null>");
    
    
        Console.WriteLine(json3);
    
        var root3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json3);
        Console.WriteLine(root3.ProductInfo ?? "<null>");
    }
}

class Root{
    [JsonProperty("head_test")]
    public string? Head { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("product_info")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonObjectToStringConverter<object?>))]
    public string? ProductInfo { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("tail_test")]
    public string? Tail { get; set; }
}

class JsonObjectToStringConverter<TValue> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(base.CanWrite)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => base.CanRead;

    public override bool CanWrite => base.CanWrite;

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = serializer.Deserialize<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>(reader);
        try
        {
            return token?.ToObject(objectType);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return token?.ToString();
        }

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if(value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var token = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(value);
            token.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        }

    }
}

[EDIT] My software threw another kind of excepion, here's the logged trace
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00: [22:16:14 ERR] Failed to convert [[[[[[[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]]]], [[]], [[]]]]], [[]]] to System.String
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00: System.ArgumentException: Can not convert Object to String.
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType)
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00:    at [....].JsonConverters.JsonObjectToStringConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in [...]\JsonConverters\JsonObjectToStringConverter.cs:line 37
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00: [22:16:14 ERR] Failed to convert [[[[[[[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]]]], [[]], [[]]]]], [[]]] to System.String
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00: System.ArgumentException: Can not convert Object to String.
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType)
2024-11-25 22:16 +01:00:    at [...].JsonConverters.JsonObjectToStringConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in [...]\JsonConverters\JsonObjectToStringConverter.cs:line 37

[Edit]
I've read the question Deserialize json with known and unknown fields that asks about a json with unknown properties of the type "_unknown_field_name_1": "some value", while my json is more such as
{
    "id": "<some_id>",
    "name": "<some_name>",
    "product_info": null,
    [...Other fields...]
}

My will is to manage all unknown property values (where null does appear) storing them as strings, with the json fragment in them.
If I use the
// extra fields
   [JsonExtensionData]
   private IDictionary<string, JToken> _extraStuff;

I could get the JToken but I have to use an intermediate object to store the extra stuff and process it, so I have to write custom code.

JSON.NET can already unknown fields in a IDictionary<string, JToken> marked with the JsonExtensionData attribute . This is shown in Deserialize ExtensionData. There's no need for custom code

Yes I saw that, my need was to put unknown object into strings, I don’t use additional fields by now and don’t like to carry around  dictionaries in my model objects, objects that I usually persist in PostgreSQL used as a document store

JSON.NET uses reflection to serialize anything with properties. The property can be generic, dynamic or object and JSON.NET will work. You don't need a converter for that either. Besides, ProductInfo is a string and doesn't need any kind of conversion. It can't be treated as an object.

@PanagiotisKanavos ProductInfo is a carrier for the json field product_info that in 99% of times results null. the string? ProductInfo property is an inference made by myself. I have the need to be able to inspect product info and notify by a Log.Warning at least that the inference was wrong. In the 3rd part json there are many points in which this occurs, I would like to be informed and know if my software missed something of interest, though in 99% this is not the case.

JsonReaderException indicates that your JSON is malformed, you can't write a converter to fix that, you need to get whoever generated the JSON to fix their code and provide you with well-formed JSON.  But when I posted your JSON to https://jsonlint.com/ the only error present is a complaint about the trailing comma after the value of "tail_test", which is an error that Json.NET silently ignores.  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] reproducing the JsonReaderException error?

Also, if your JSON is well-formed and you really just want to capture the raw JSON value of "product_data" in public string? ProductInfo, you can apply [JsonConverter(typeof(RawConverter))] from this answer to How can I serialize and deserialize a type with a string member that contains "raw" JSON, without escaping the JSON in the process.  Does that answer your question? If neither that nor the currently linked duplicate work for you, can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Thanks!

@dbc thanks for the link, i think I can adapt it to my needs. Thank you very much!
